# Passing SQL Table name as parameter

Tags: sql, sqlite, parameters

I'm working on a SQL query that needs to change Tables depending an input parameter.

I want something like this:

```
da.SelectCommand = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT max(TimeStamp) TimeStamp FROM [@Sensor]", conn2);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Sensor", DbType.Object).Value = nombre_sensor;
```

I've heard is not possible to do this, and you have to use `string.Format` but I have no idea how, any solutions please?

Comment: You can only parameterize constants, so you cannot parameterize table names, column names, function names, or SQL keywords.

Comment: What happens then if I do something like this?

string query = string.Format("SELECT max(TimeStamp) TimeStamp FROM [{0}]", table_name); @GordonLinoff

Comment: @Juanma you can, but you have to think about sql injection

Comment: @Juanma . . . That is pretty much what you have to do.  Unfortunately, SQL doesn't have a good method parameterizing identifiers.